# iPAD Chrome CORS cookie sharing

Tags: google-chrome, ipad, cookies, cross-domain, ipados

I have a web application which loaded in the iFrame of other web application (both are from same domain).
I have enabled "Allowed - Cross site-Website tracking" option but it loses session when accessing site in iframe.

It works fine with the same configuration in iPhone Chrome and Safari (separate configuration under Setting -> Safari -> Prevent Cross-Site Tracking.

[image]